# Pi 3 as a Wi-Fi Repeater

Tags: raspbian

Since the Pi 3 has an on-board Wi-Fi adapter is it possible to build a Wi-Fi repeater without using Ethernet as input and without using a Wi-Fi dongle?

Comment: Yes, and there are plenty of tutorials out there that cover the topic. Please do some basic research before you ask a question. **We are not a search engine**.

Comment: Most of the tutorials that are available are based in raspberry pi 2 in which wifi dongles were used hence asked this question

Comment: Here is a tutorial that I found after about 30 seconds of looking: https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/ .You can find many more simply by searching for tutorials about using the Pi 3 as a Wi-Fi access point.

Comment: As hinted here in the comments and in the answer, make sure you are searching also for "extender" if that is truly what you want to do.

Comment: @Darth Vader I typed "raspberry pi wfi repeater" into a search engine and this page was the top hit. No need to be so unhelpful in your response. Why don't you at least link to one of the tutorials?

Answer (score 5):

I think the reason you found it so hard to find tutorials is perhaps not being specific enough in your search queries. And also not realizing that a Wi-Fi repeater and Wi-Fi access point are quite similar.

I'm going to give you a brief overview of how to do what I think you are after. The important thing to note here is the Wi-Fi chip on the Pi 3, BCM43438, is supported by the open-source brcmfmac driver. This is what allows the repeater/access point functionality.

Here are the basic steps:

You need to install dnsmasq which is the DNS DHCP server. You also need to install hostapad which allows the Wi-Fi chip to be used as an access point. So in the terminal run `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq hostapd`.

To ensure the Pi remains connected to the router you need to give it a static IP address. You can do this in your router settings or on the Pi. To do it from the Pi end:

1. Open the `dhcpcd` configuration file with `sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.con`. Go to the bottom of the file and add this line, `denyinterfaces wlan0`. Exit the file with saving.
2. Next run `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and edit the `wlan0`, to give this result:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0  
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 172.24.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 172.24.1.0
    broadcast 172.24.1.255
    #wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

3. Restart `dhcpcd` using `sudo service dhcpcd restart`, reload the configuration for `wlan0` by running `sudo ifdown wlan0; sudo ifup wlan0`.

Configure `hostpad` by first running `sudo nano /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`. The file needs to look like this:

```
# This is the name of the WiFi interface we configured above
interface=wlan0

# Use the nl80211 driver with the brcmfmac driver
driver=nl80211

# This is the name of the network
ssid=Pi3-AP

# Use the 2.4GHz band
hw_mode=g

# Use channel 6
channel=6

# Enable 802.11n
ieee80211n=1

# Enable WMM
wmm_enabled=1

# Enable 40MHz channels with 20ns guard interval
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]

# Accept all MAC addresses
macaddr_acl=0

# Use WPA authentication
auth_algs=1

# Require clients to know the network name
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

# Use WPA2
wpa=2

# Use a pre-shared key
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

# The network passphrase
wpa_passphrase=raspberry

# Use AES, instead of TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Now run `sudo nano /etc/default/hostapd`, replace `#DAEMON_CONF=""` with `DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"`. You can then exit the file with saving it.

`dnsmasq` now needs to be configured. First run:

```
sudo mv /etc/dnsmasq.conf /etc/dnsmasq.conf.orig  
sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.con
```

Paste in the file:

```
interface=wlan0      # Use interface wlan0  
listen-address=172.24.1.1 # Explicitly specify the address to listen on  
bind-interfaces      # Bind to the interface to make sure we aren't sending things elsewhere  
server=8.8.8.8       # Forward DNS requests to Google DNS  
domain-needed        # Don't forward short names  
bogus-priv           # Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.  
dhcp-range=172.24.1.50,172.24.1.150,12h # Assign IP addresses between 172.24.1.50 and 172.24.1.150 with a 12 hour lease time
```

Setup IPV4 forwarding:

Run `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`, the line `#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` needs to become `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`. Next run `sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"`, to activate the file.

To ensure the Pi's internet connection is shared to the connected devices run the following commands:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

So that these stick when the Pi reboots run `sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"`. Then run `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` and above the line `exit 0` add `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat`.

Finally run:

```
sudo service hostapd start  
sudo service dnsmasq start
```

Which sets the necessary services running and everything should now work.

For more information on what some of these commands are doing you can check this [website](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/).

Comment: This did not work for me on raspbian stretch with the latest firmware. I'm pretty sure my problem lies with the dhcpcd client. Some notable errors include it saying that it failed to to load all interfaces, and `systemctl status dhcpcd.service` furtermore states that this is because there is already some interface defined in /etc/network/interfaces (which is not the case, as it only contains the wlan0 setup from this answer). Moreover,  raspbian complains that dhcpd.service changed on disk and that I should reload it, but reloading  does nothing.

Comment: The rest of it seems to work however, as `ifconfig` shows wlan0 as up with the right ip address. I can even connect to the Pi from another device (running macOS) without any complaints, but no websites actually. Wifi on on the Pi also stopped being able to load any websites. (although the ifconfig output looks okay, as stated)  Any help?