# The File "etc/network/interfaces" is basically empty

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi

I've been trying to setup the Pi as a WiFi AP, so that I can use it in Hotels to allow multiple devices to use the same WiFi connection. On the net there are multiple tutorials on how to do this. Such as: 
[Pi 3 as a Wi-Fi Repeater](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67601/pi-3-as-a-wi-fi-repeater/72897#72897)

All works well up to the points where you should edit sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces. On my system this file is basically empty and has no references to either wlan0 or lan0. What I have in my "interfaces" file is:

```
interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd

For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:

source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong and I've read through a lot of the tutorials. Could it be that the newest Kernel Version (4.9) has changes compared to the earlier version with regards to the networking?

Answer (score 7):

There is NOTHING WRONG. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for an explanation of the network settings in Stretch.

The `interfaces` file is largely empty because **it is not necessary** - I used to run a late Wheezy (using `dhcpcd` without one). It was only used because `dhcpcd` was incompletely setup, prior to Stretch.

The problem is no one has updated the tutorials.

I have not recently used the Pi in such a manner, and I am not sure the tutorials you are following are the best practice, but you should be able to adapt them - either that or go back to an old Raspbian.

See [Wireless Access Point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) for a Foundation tutorial.

**NOTE** this is also not up to date, and will need to be adapted.

You will need to consider the following issues:-

1. Predictable Network Interface Names
2. Disable `dhcpcd`, either entirely or for the interfaces which do not need it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. And there was me thinking I'm to dumb to set this up ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to put back the `/etc/network/interfaces` style network configuration, you need to uninstall the packages `raspberrypi-net-mods` and `dhcpcd5`.

I did so because I wanted to set up a token for building the local part of the IPv6 addresses (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/335633/253665) but found no way how to do this with dhcpcd.

**Update**

A simpler solution is to disable the `dhcpcd.service`:

```
systemctl mask dhcpcd.service
```